# undefined method `<<' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client

I have this strange error (for me) I can not figure out why is happening.

Sometimes when I call `RestClient.get 'http://google.com'` I got a response and some times I get this error `undefined method '<<' for true:TrueClass`

I am using Rails 4.1.8, Ruby 2.1.5p273 and RestClient 1.7.2

```
    2.1.5 :010 > RestClient.get 'https://google.com'
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for true:TrueClass
    from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rest-client-1.7.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:525:in `log_request'
    from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rest-client-1.7.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:410:in `transmit'
    from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rest-client-1.7.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:176:in `execute'
    from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rest-client-1.7.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:41:in `execute'
    from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rest-client-1.7.2/lib/restclient.rb:65:in `get'
    from (irb):10
    from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you show code where you handle response from `http://google.com`, and where you user `<<` in that context. Problem is that you call `<<` on something that is `true` and not `array`

Comment: @Nermin: He doesn't. RestClient does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RestClient.log` is set to `true`. Find where that happens by intercepting the setter:

```
def RestClient.log=(value)
  raise "HERE!"
end
```

then just wait till the exception is triggered, and see from the stack trace who assigns silly values. :)